# 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] for Lubuntu after I input sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, lubuntu

I have recently shifted from Ubuntu to Lubuntu 19.10, and I was deleting the packages which were usually using GNOME. I unfortunately happened to delete my Software Center and update center. I cannot update my system right now and it's really a mess. I receive this error message when I try to run `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease 
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80] 
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
Err:6 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com' 
Err:7 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com' 
Err:8 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com' 
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_19.10 InRelease
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_19.10 Release 404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80] 
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu eoan Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_19.10 Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is my sources.kist after `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse deb-src http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-proposed main multiverse universe restricted
```

Comment: Now you removed ALL repositories.

Comment: old-releases will not have bionic (it's support), plus there are no country mirrors (in.old-releases is invalid).  You have many errors.  Shifting from Ubuntu to Lubuntu alone would not create these issues (if you moved from an unsupported release, please specify as only 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade was tested and you may have other issues too)

Answer (score 0):

You clearly copied those sources from someplace else and much older, which wasn't wise.

This won't work, because Eoan (19.10) is not OLD (unsupported) yet:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
```

Instead, try this:

```
deb http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
```

As you go through and correct the mistake on all those lines, you might discover some duplicates. Exact duplicates will raise warnings - delete one of the duplicates...it doesn't matter which duplicate gets deleted.